# Sorting string of numeric in powershell

Tags: powershell, ps1

I have retrieved an array of strings that are

```
0.0.1
0.0.10
0.0.2
```

Since this is string with multiple dots I had to remove dots to compare them which I did it following way

```
$array = $r.Links.outerText.replace('/','') | 
Where {$_ -notmatch $filter} | 
% {$_ -replace('\.', '')} | 
sort {[double]$_}
```

This gives me

```
001                                                                                                                                                                       
002
010
```

but now I want to retrieve the original value of the last value which is 0.0.10.
How should I do that? or is there any other approach to sort without replacing the dots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the string manipulation *inside the scriptblock passed to `sort`*:

```
... |sort {[double]($_ -replace '\.')}
```

This way the sorting still works, but the underlying data stays intact

---

With this in mind, for version-like strings it's probably better to cast to `[version]` and let the internal comparison logic of that data type work it's magic:

```
PS ~> -split '0.0.1 0.0.10 0.0.2' |sort {[version]$_}
0.0.1
0.0.2
0.0.10
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of [version] type. Thanks for pointing that out. I just relaced [double] with [version] to make it work.

Comment: Provided the strings *are* versions, the ```[version]``` approach is probably more reliable - for example the string manipulation route will give an unexpected sort order for e.g. ```0.28.1``` (=> 281) vs ```0.2.91``` (=> 291).